# Template function without explicit usage of type, strange overload ranking

Tags: c++, templates, overload-resolution

I couldn't come up with a better title for my question. Basically it resumes to the following code:

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename T> // generic
void f(T)
{
    std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl;
}

template<typename T> 
void f(int)
{
    std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl;
}

int main()
{   
    f(42);        // calls generic f(T)
    f<int>(42);   // calls f(int)
    f<int>(42.2); // also calls f(int)
}
```

[<kbd>Live on Coliru</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b143d4515422774e)

My question(s):

1. Is the second overload syntactically OK? The type is not used anywhere in it. It seems to be OK, as the program compiles with both g++ and clang++.
2. How does the compiler choose which overload to call? I understand maybe why `f(42)` calls the generic `f(T)`, however why does `f<int>(42)` and `f<int>(42.2)` result in the second overload being called?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Yes. It's just that T can't be deduced from the argument. That's ok because you've supplied a template argument in (2) and (3).
2. It will choose the deduced version (1) if you don't specify T when you call it (example 1). If you specify T at the call site it won't try to deduce T because you already told it what T was (example 2 and 3).

Comment: That's what I believed about 1. However, regarding 2, why does it chose the second overload? There is no type deduction going on, why wouldn't it chose the first? Because `int` in the template type matches perfectly the function parameter? But even if I call it with a double same thing happen.

Comment: the first form requires type deduction. Since you have supplied all template arguments, the second form is a 'better' match because it can be selected with fewer logic operations.

Comment: I would have thought that there will be 2 overloads produced by the instantiation: `f<int>(int)` for the first, and... `f<int>(int)` for the second. Which IMO should have led to an ambiguity.

Comment: there's only an ambiguity if the two candidates are of equal strength. To deduce the first requires 2 logic steps (1, deduce argument type, 2 supply that as template argument). The second requires only one logic step (supply template argument). Therefore the second will be preferred *however* if the template argument needs to be deduced then the second form cannot be a candidate at all, because there is no argument with which to deduce T.

Comment: it's probably worth noting that a real program would never use the second form. One would prefer either an overloaded non-template function or an explicit specialisation of the general (first) form.

Comment: Thanks. Yes indeed, I'd never use this in real code. However it happened by mistake, when I was trying something and forgot to remove `template<typename T>` from the definition of the second overload. And, to my surprise, that made a huge difference in the output.